# Is there a way to turn off all pop-up alerts in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, popups, alert

Is there a config option to turn off those little yellow balloons that pop up in the lower right corner of the screen?

Also the found new hardware dialog that shows up regardless of whether the hardware is actually new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so many kind of alerts you can disable... [Here is one of these](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/disable-notification-balloons-in-xp/)

For [Security Alerts](http://www.pchell.com/support/winxpsecurityalerts.shtml)

For [New Programs Installed](http://www.xp-tips.com/disable-new-programs-installed.html)

Also, never forget that Google is your best friend for this kind of question/request ;)